# Sending JSON string to my backend code to add it to my DB but it's not adding anything

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, ajax

I've been stuck on this problem for a good bit

I'm trying to add an object to my database through jQuery/AJAX. Apparently, there are no errors but it's not adding anything to my DB.

This is my JS/JQuery code:

```
var student = new Object();
student.Name = $("#txtNameAdd").val();
student.Age = $("#txtAgeAdd").val();
student.Email = $("#txtEmailAdd").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/AddStudent",
    data: "{'studentJSONString':'" + JSON.stringify(student) + "'}",
    success: function (response) {
        $("#lblSuccessAdd").text("Success!");
        $("#lblSuccessAdd").css("display", "block");
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseJSON);
    }
});
```

My JS code points towards this code I have in my Default.aspx page code:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void AddStudent(string studentJSONString)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer converter = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Student a = converter.Deserialize<Student>(studentJSONString);
        WebMethods.AddStudent(a);
    }
```

Which points to this code in my WebMethods.cs class

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        MasterStudent master = new MasterStudent();
        master.AddStudent(student);
    }
```

And finally that goes to my class library and finishes with this method in MasterStudent:

```
    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(student.Name))
        {
            throw new Exception("There's no name");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(student.Email))
        {
            throw new Exception("There's no email");
        }

        using (studentEntities model = new studentEntities())
        {
            model.student.Add(student);
            model.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I run the code and the Console doesn't log any problems but it also doesn't do anything.

I have run very similar code on a Forms application with no problems so I'm kind of in a pickle right now. Does anyone know why it keeps failing?

Comment: Do not answer your question within the question. We have answer posts for that.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried attaching a debugger to it and verifying that the student object is not null prior to model.SaveChanges() ?

Try debugging and verifying that the student string is being converted to an actual Student object first.

If it is, then try profiling the DB and validate any commands issued.

Comment: I tried running breakpoints in my code and I just realized something incredibly weird, I have an AJAX code that does work and that does activate my breakpoints, but my add method doesn't activate anything so something is definetly very wrong here

Answer (score -1):

```
var student = new Object();
student.Name = $("#txtNameAdd").val();
student.Age = $("#txtAgeAdd").val();
student.Email = $("#txtEmailAdd").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/AddStudent",
    data: student,
    success: function (response) {
        $("#lblSuccessAdd").text("Success!");
        $("#lblSuccessAdd").css("display", "block");
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseJSON);
    }
});
```

Then you can to point to this WebMethod.

```
[WebMethod]
public static void AddStudent(Student student)
{
    MasterStudent master = new MasterStudent();
    master.AddStudent(student);
}
```

Try this.

Comment: You could provide an explanation about what they were doing wrong as well as an explanation of how your code fixes the problem. Also you can use four spaces to cause the code to render as a block.

Answer (score -1):

So I actually did find a solution shortly after posting my question, I changed my JQuery AJAX call to look like this:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/AddStudent",
    data: "{'studentJSONString':'" + JSON.stringify(student) + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        $("#lblSuccessAdd").text("Success!");
        $("#lblSuccessAdd").css("display", "block");
    },
    error: function (response) {
        $("#lblErrorAdd").text(response.responseJSON.Message);
        $("#lblErrorAdd").css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

And it actually works now! so either the dataType or contentType were very important for what I was trying to do

Thanks for your answers everybody